# How can I programmatically get the JNA version being used at runtime?

Tags: java, jna

I'm trying to print the JNA version being used to my logs, at runtime.

How do I get the version of JNA through code at runtime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current JNA version is written at build time to a constant `VERSION` in the appropriately-named [`Version`](http://java-native-access.github.io/jna/5.6.0/javadoc/com/sun/jna/Version.html#VERSION) interface.  That interface is package private, but is implemented by the [`Native`](http://java-native-access.github.io/jna/5.6.0/javadoc/com/sun/jna/Native.html) class, making the constant publicly available from `Native`. (Linters may complain.)  So you can simply do:

```
import com.sun.jna.Native;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("JNA Version: " + Native.VERSION);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
JNA Version: 5.6.0
```

You can also get the version of the native bits, which follow a different numbering scheme than the overall project version (which is incremented with new mappings that don't change the compiled native portions), but may be relevant in some contexts:

```
System.out.println("JNA Native Version: " + Native.VERSION_NATIVE);
```

The `Native` class also exposes a `boolean` [`isCompatibleVersion()`](http://java-native-access.github.io/jna/5.5.0/javadoc/com/sun/jna/Native.html#isCompatibleVersion-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) method which you can use to check whether JNA is at least the specified version or higher.

Comment: Unfortunatelly VERSION and VERSION_NATIVE are not visible, so your answer does not work.

Comment: @CCCCoder3 My answer works. I just executed it. Did you try it?  Did you notice I specified the `Native` class which exposes the package-private constants in the `Version` interface?   Exactly how does it "not work" for you?  Are you getting compiler errors/ Runtime errors? Empty results?

Comment: The constants in an interface are by default `public`.  The reason you can't use `Version.VERSION` is because the interface itself is package private. However, the `Native` class is `public` so its iherited (`public`) field `VERSION` is visible.

Comment: It does not work for me, maybe I'm using a different version than you? But if you see the docs of Version, you see it is PACKAGE PUBLIC. Native won't be able to change that when it implements Version. Not sure why you think it magically becomes public.

Comment: It would really help me to understand what you mean "does not work for you".  Exactly what error are you seeing?

Comment: variable VERSION is not visible when I do `Native.VERSION`. Why do you think VERSION is public on Native if it is clear package private on Version class?

Comment: It is not the field itself that is package private, it's the class.  The field, because it is in an interface, is automatically public, static, and final.  So when the class is implemented, the subclass (implementing class) inherits a `public` field.

Comment: I just created the following 3 classes:  `interface Test1 { int foo = 42; }`, `public class Test2 implements Test1 { }` (in the same package), and `public class Test3 { public static void main(String[] args) { System.out.println(Test2.foo); } }` in a different package.  I got `42`.   This did not (obviously) work with `Test1.foo`.